# Set the "File/Product version" of a Windows' binary to arbitrary string

Tags: windows, resources, version, exe, semantic-versioning

all. Currently, I want to set the version of a Windows' application (exe), dynamically-linked library (dll) or statically-linked library (lib) to a one using not the standard version format `<major>.<minor>.<patch>.<build>` (example: `3.2.0.73`) but the [semantic versioning 2.0](http://semver.org/#semantic-versioning-200)'s one (example: `3.2.0-RC3+73`). Looking at the specifications of the version information resource ([VERSIONINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx)) both the `FILEVERSION` and the `PRODUCTVERSION` fields consist of:

> two 32-bit integers, defined by four 16-bit integers

Hence, both version fields should be specified as having 4 version segments/parts/numbers where each of them is 16-bit (unsigned short integer) wide:

```
#define VER_FILEVERSION             3,10,349,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "3.10.349.0\0"

#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          3,10,0,0
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "3.10\0"

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION  VER_PRODUCTVERSION
FILEFLAGSMASK   VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
FILEFLAGS       (VER_PRIVATEBUILD|VER_PRERELEASE|VER_DEBUG)

// ...

BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName",      VER_COMPANYNAME_STR
            VALUE "FileDescription",  VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR
            VALUE "FileVersion",      VER_FILEVERSION_STR

            // ...

            VALUE "ProductVersion",   VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
        END
    END

    // ...
END
```

The situation is different about the string variants of the corresponding fields. Scanning the same specification near the bottom and more particularly the section:

> Remarks -> string-name

what becomes obvious is that those string representations of the 4-segment 16-bit file and product versions, could contain any characters:

> FileVersion | Version number of the file. For example, "3.10" or "5.00.**RC2**". This string is required.
>
> ...
>
> ProductVersion | Version of the product with which the file is distributed. For example, "3.10" or "5.00.**RC2**". This string is required.

So, the first question (**Q1**): is it officially specified that the contents of the string representations can have arbitrary contents? **Q2**: Next, even though I have set both fields to have the same semantic versioning 2.0-formatted version string, [only the product version appears to be affected](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNa0-zp9_eR6QlaLBbxfUxnwT29Hxv3_KqpWsSlRde2HjJlR6-SyIQd69r3pg67_w/photo/AF1QipMdnAKj_8vd6Qzy_hkCiqeS0uuMnMonTjbD8kjy?key=bzV2MFVodExTSnhEcWhpWTZWekl1Tjh3M18xcjJB). This is strange since both fields have the same specification that they should contain a string but only one of them is actually alternated. Also both fields don't explicitly state that the `VALUE "FileVersion"` field can be assigned any string value, but an explicit example is given of such value containing characters different from `0-9` and `.`:

> 5.00.**RC2**

Thus again the restriction over the file version field compared to the product version one is paradoxical. The third question (**Q3**): is there a more detailed specification and reference for the `VERSIONINFO` resouce, which provides the full set of possible parameters and parameter values? Currently, I don't see any description and details about the possible values of the `FILEFLAGS` property: `(VER_PRIVATEBUILD|VER_PRERELEASE|VER_DEBUG)`. Here a value of interest is the `VER_PRERELEASE` one which matches the meaning of the `PRERELEASE` version part in the semantic versioning 2.0 specification.

Answer (score 0):

The version information in a PE file starts with a fixed block ([`VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997(VS.85).aspx)) followed by any number of freeform strings.

The string and flag combinations are not really verified anywhere and even the documentation cannot make up its mind about which strings are required:

> VS_FF_PRIVATEBUILD File was not built using standard release procedures. If this value is given, the StringFileInfo block [**must**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx) contain a PrivateBuild string.

VS

> VS_FF_PRIVATEBUILD The file was not built using standard release procedures. If this flag is set, the StringFileInfo structure [**should**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997(VS.85).aspx) contain a PrivateBuild entry.

**Q1**:

> [An arbitrary Unicode string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646987(v=vs.85).aspx). The szKey member can be one or more of the following values. These values are guidelines only...

**Q2**:

Some applications/fields display the number from the fixed block and some use the "standard" strings.

**Q3**:

> Contains a bitmask that specifies the Boolean attributes of the file. [This member can include one or more of the following values...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997(VS.85).aspx)